# Inflate data encoded with ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE in php

Tags: php, compression, deflate

Saying a compressed string:

```
$compressed   = gzdeflate('Compress me', 9, ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE);
```

How uncompress it?

```
$uncompressed = gzinflate($compressed);

Warning: gzinflate(): data error in php shell code on line 1
```

Comment: Remove the last `ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE` argument. It turns out, that `ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP ` is not working, too. Only `ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW ` which is default does work.

Comment: Actually I must use this algo to compress the data, then I am looking for uncompress it.

Comment: It looks like this is an "binary" encoding problem. Only in raw mode, it is ok. If you var_dump() the compressed string, you will see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can use `gzcompress()` and `gzuncompress()` to get deflated zlib  encoding.

The compressed string is the same as using `gzdeflate()` and the inflating (uncompressing) works without any error.

```php
$compressed = gzcompress('Compress me', 9, ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE);
var_dump($compressed);
```

> string(19) "xs-(J-.VM║\000╝?"

```php
$uncompressed = gzuncompress($compressed);
var_dump($uncompressed);
```

> string(11) "Compress me"

Comment: You are right, ``gzuncompress`` can read ``gzdeflate('Compress me', 9, ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE)`` !